How does anyone know for sure who the Prime Minister is?
France is famous for tourism, food, and above all, bureaucraty.
When a Prime Minister is heading out, there is a decree saying so. When a new Prime Minister is appointed, a decree is published in the government gazette.
It is my understanding that in the UK, the outgoing PM goes to see the Queen or King, tells them they're resigning, and suggests someone to take the office. The monarch invites this person and appoints them as their PM.
Is there anything official, a decree, a publication somewhere, or does the newly appointed PM just go to Westminster, say to everyone there: "The monarch said I'm the boss now!", and everyone just goes with it?

It was published in the government's The Gazette in a traditional but subtle way.  See https://www.thegazette.co.uk/notice/4668240 with the list of Lords Commissioners of His Majesty’s Treasury.  Keir Starmer's name was first, making him First Lord of the Treasury (and implicitly therefore Prime Minister - see the Number 10 letter box).  Rachel Reeves's name was second making her Second Lord (and implicitly therefore Chancellor of the Exchequer). The other names are some of the government whips.

Yes - Sunak and Starmer's meetings with the King are published in the Court Circular, the official listing of the day's Royal events. The entry for July 5th states:

The Rt Hon Rishi Sunak MP had an audience of The King this morning and
tendered his resignation as Prime Minister and First Lord of the
Treasury which His Majesty was graciously pleased to accept.   Mrs
Murty was also received by The King.
His Majesty received in audience the Rt Hon Sir Keir Starmer MP today
and requested him to form a new Administration. The Rt Hon Sir Keir
Starmer MP accepted The King’s offer and kissed hands upon his
appointment as Prime Minister and First Lord of the Treasury.
Lady Starmer was also received by His Majesty.

The list of business transacted at Privy Council meetings is also published, with the meeting for July 6th including Sir Keir and several of his ministers swearing or affirming their oaths of office:

This day the Right Honourable Sir Keir Starmer KCB KC (Prime Minister)
did, by His Majesty’s command, make solemn affirmation as First Lord
of the Treasury.


I just spent a disproportionate amount of time studying and comparing the wordings of the different items on the list of business transactions at the Privy Council. Would it be appropriate for politics.SE to ask about the finer difference between "being sworn", "being admitted, on affirmation", "making solemn affirmation", "being declared", and "taking oath of office", or is this rather a question for one of the English Usage sites?

@Schmuddi It is helpful to think of these as a collective mildly archaic form whose fine details are in substance irrelevant to the big picture of someone getting a particular job.

@ohwilleke: you are absolutely right - and yet, all of these seemingly minor details have some kind of meaning behind them, even if that meaning has lost all significance (or indeed, if the meaning has been forgotten).

@Schmuddi: please ask it here, and I may attempt to answer.

There are those who view taking an oath as incompatible with their belief system (some portion of atheists, as well as many quakers (these sets are not necessarily disjoint...), for instance).  For those, the traditional formalism is to have them make an affirmation which effectively means the same thing.  See also the US Constitution, which consistently uses terminology like "Oath or Affirmation", "do solemnly swear (or affirm)"

If anyone else wonders whether Starmer actually kissed the king's hand: TIL that kissing hands is a legal term in the UK.

@SteveMelnikoff: I've just posted my question: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/88271/membership-and-offices-in-the-privy-council-what-is-the-significance-of-the-di

OP mentions that we (France) are known for the bureaucracy (which is true to some extent, it wildly depends on the proximity, i.e. when you write to a gov't entity you fail by default, when you go in person to the town hall you are likely to succeed independently of the raw documents). Anyway, at least we do not have this kind of reverence, including "kissing hands", which now I know thanks to @Heinzi is a legal term. I am not a native speaker of English so U do not exactly understand what "was graciously pleased" means but it sounds really rigid as well. That was the FR-UK rant of the day :)

@BuckThorn The King is "His Majesty", not "His (Royal) Highness"; HRH is used for princes and princesses. Also, violating the oath of office is not perjury (which is lying under oath). In theory, misfeasance in public office is more likely; but in practice, the worst that happens to politicians is that they are forced to resign.

The Court Circular also appears to be available online directly from the royal website, but that version isn't up to date enough to show the entry from July 5th yet - it currently has a July 4th entry so I imagine will include the July 5th entry in the next few days. https://www.royal.uk/media-centre/court-circulars

To add to CDJB's answer:

All ministerial appointments are nowadays published on the Government's website; here's the July 2024 page. Initially, the only appointment listed was the new Prime Minister's. The page was updated several times over the next few days as senior ministers, junior ministers and whips were added.
In a curious mix of old and new, the PM's appointment was also announced on the Royal Family's official X (formerly Twitter) feed, along with a photo of the King and PM shaking hands.
A list of the entire Government appears in Hansard (the official report of everything that happens in the House of Commons), in the edition for the first day of each parliamentary session. Here's the one for 7 November 2023; the list begins on p17, with the PM at the top.


Hardly surprising. The King may dismiss a Prime Minister in the event of a crisis. Technically the appointment is approved by the King. Even then, if they lose the leadership of the party or coalition, they are expected to step aside. Many citizens of the USA are unaware that the Electoral College chooses the President, and in the extreme, their own write-in candidate. Once chosen though, there are no "backsies" for them. In Australia, most people could not name the last 5 PM's in order.

@mckenzm many people in the UK could not name the last 5 PM's in order, and that's only a 5 year span

I would count all that as circumstantial evidence only. The house may claim whatever (and how they would know anything, even if they intend to report the truth, is the actual question here!) -- but one becomes Prime Minister by being appointed by the King or Queen, and of that appointment there must be an official document, or maybe public proclamations by authorized riding messengers, or whatever.

The King doesn't tell Westminster who is boss, it is the other way round.
The King appointing the PM is a formality - everyone knows who the PM is before it happens. The King is not making a decision, he is rubber stamping a decision that has already been made. In the case of a general election, this decision is made by the public choice picking which party holds a majority and thus which party's leader is now PM. Kier Starmer did not go to the King until the election was (almost) complete and everyone knew that he had a majority in Parliament.
When the PM is changed mid-Parliament, the decision is made by the party choosing its new leader, but again that decision is made before the new leader goes to the King. Thus, when Rishi Sunak became PM his appointment as Party Leader was made before the meeting with the King.
So the new PM isn't coming back from the King and saying to Westminster, "The King says I'm the boss now", the PM is going to the King and saying "Westminster says I'm the boss now".

@DanielHatton I would say that's another example of the same point I was making: the Monarch will not appoint the PM until it is clear who the PM is.

In '74, Heath attempted to form a coalition and only resigned when he was unable to do so. It was still the case that Wilson went to the King when it was already known that he would be PM. The King is not making a decision, he is rubber-stamping a decision already made.

It is worth noting that the new Westminster parliament had not met on 5th July 2024 and would not meet until 9th July to elect a Speaker: in fact when Keir Starmer went to see the King in the morning of 5th July, several constituencies had not counted their votes and did not know who their MP would be.  But enough had and the result was obvious and Rishi Sunak had resigned, advising the King to send for Keir Starmer, so that is what happened.

In 1945, it was not clear that Attlee would remain leader of the Labour Party - he had been elected in 1935, but most of the 1945 Labour MPs were new.  He went to the palace anyway, and (from Wikipedia) the notoriously laconic Attlee and the famously tongue-tied King stood in silence; Attlee finally volunteered the remark, "I've won the election". The King replied "I know. I heard it on the Six O'Clock News".

Reminds me of the Berlin subway. When the automatic voice say "stay back" it is really time to get in.

I'm sure the King or Queen could take initiative to appoint a PM if there is e.g. a stalemate in parliament. I'm also almost sure that they could flatly refuse to appoint the guy or girl who has the majority if they find them unfit for some reason, even though that would be a constitutional crisis. Absent a constitution, there is not even a statute establishing the office of a PM; centuries of custom and precedent shape the government. The one entirely indisputable and unambiguous fact is that the monarch is the head of state.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica If our monarch was in the business of rejecting unsuitable candidates we'd have been spared at least one, probably two, of the last few. The head of state role of the monarch is entirely ceremonial.

@JackAidley Where is that written?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica That's not the logic by which the British government operates. The monarch is the head of state, and that role is entirely ceremonial unless and until there is a bloody good reason for it not to be.

@wizzwizz4 No disagreement there. The "unless and until" was the little objection I had to this apodictic answer. The answer is not wrong -- it presents what's happened the last 200 years or so -- but rather to sure of itself. (I'm tempted to say: The paradox of precedence is that it is the accumulation of its violations.)

This doesn't answer the question "How does anyone know for sure". The way you know for sure is that the Palace has published the appointment in the Court Circular.

Prior to 1834, the monarch did try choosing Prime Ministers who didn't have the support of a parliamentary majority. Peel was the last.

Westminster doesn't tell the King who's boss; it advises him as to whom he should appoint.  Yes, in practice it amounts to Westminster telling the King who's boss, and, through them, the voters of their several constituencies, but formally speaking it is the King who appoints the PM.  This question is about the formalities, so answering it in terms of the practicalities isn't particularly helpful.

@phoog Sure, if you want to completely misunderstand the British system, you can obsess over ceremony rather than reality.
